# Best way to do a 2 pane web app for iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I'm making an iPad web-app, and the client would like it to have two panes (both separately scrolling), much like the iPad settings app. What is the best way to go about this while still maintaining compatibility with older versions of iOS?

Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that it should seem somewhat native, so no two finger scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use two container elements (DIV for example) and use the following styles

```
#first,
#second {
  float: left;
  height: 500px; // or whatever fits your needs
  width: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll   
}
```

please note than in iOS overflowing content needs to be scrolled with two fingers when using it in a Web Application and it is not possible to do this with one finger like in an native application.. see also the [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

Comment: I should've clarified that I want to avoid 2 finger scrolling. Thanks anyway.

Comment: oh that indeed is a tricky one... I think that could only be set up by observing touchdown and the scroll event. So on scroll you can determine where the user started scrolling... but I would think that as a hacky solution... I would rather suggest that you have one scrollable area and one is fixed... please update your question :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite simply by having 2 `<div>` elements occupying 50% of the screen each, and individually controlling their overflow to scroll.

At its simplest css such as the following will suffice:

```
#left{
    width:50%;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    overflow-y:scroll   
}

#right{
    width:50%;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    overflow-y:scroll    
}
```

I have kept these separate so you could control the left and right side  individually (ie, you might want left to be 40% and right 60%. Or maybe you want the left fixed and the right scrolling).

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates this working: http://jsfiddle.net/tFJeS/1/